# Does Sql Server 2005 Require Sync Framework Install?

Tags: sql-server-2005, microsoft-sync-framework

What I have found on the 'net seems a little ambiguous whether or not something needs to be installed on the server to use the Sync Framework with SQL Server 2005.

My interpretation is no, that the ADO.NET'ness of the product reaches out to the server (assuming appropriately trackable tables exist).

My goal is to use SQL Compact on the client and Sync with SQL Server 2005 with no install on the server.

A little help would be great!

Thanks,

rusty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the change tracking infrastructure (SQL Server 2008 Change Tracking or Triggers etc), you will not need to install any Sync Framework components on the SQL Server machine to be able to include it in a Sync topology.

Cheers,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SQL Server 2005 does not need the Microsoft Sync Framework installed.